cache control no-cache="Set-Cookie"
There is ask to add no-cache="Set-Cookie" attribute in cache control header. I am looking for some insights how this will impact the webapps.
We have front end and backend code which read and set the cookies . Now If we add this attribute in cache control header

Will the page and its response will get cache on Apache and CDN?
Will there be any issue in reading or writing on the existing
cookies.
We have persisted cookied related with user profile and login
information. Will there be any impact on those?

